# I'm getting Type error when I use forwardRef in NextJS + Typescript App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-ref, react-forwardref, next.js13

I've a form for add item to cart in my NextJS + TS app. This form is a separate component and I use forwardRef in this component but I'm getting this error.

[forwardRef Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1T4e.png)

How can i fix this error. Thanks a lot!

***Food.tsx Component***

```js
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { FormEvent, Key, useRef } from "react";
import { FiPlus } from "react-icons/fi";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import useAddItemToCart from "../hooks/useAddItemToCart";
import { addItemToCart } from "../store/cartSlice";
import FoodForm from "./FoodForm";

const Food: React.FC<{
  id: Object;
  title: String;
  desc: String;
  price: Number;
  kit: Boolean;
  category: String;
  ingredients: Array<string>;
  image: String;
  index: Key;
}> = ({ id, title, desc, price, kit, category, index, ingredients, image }) => {
  const amountInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const { handlerAddItemToCart: handlerSubmit, amountIsValid } =
    useAddItemToCart(id, title, price, image, amountInputRef);

  return (
    <div
      key={index}
      className="col-span-1 w-full bg-theme-dark-grey rounded-[30px] py-3"
    >
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between gap-x-3 min-w-full min-h-[145px] max-h-[145px] h-full pl-4 pr-2 py-2">
        <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col h-full justify-between">
          <Link href={`/food/${id}`}>
            <h2
              data-testid="food-title"
              className="capitalize text-lg mb-1 font-medium"
            >
              {title}
            </h2>
            <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap">
              {ingredients.length > 7
                ? ingredients.slice(0, 7).map((el, i) => (
                    <p
                      key={i}
                      className="text-theme-dark-grey2 text-sm font-medium leading-2"
                    >
                      {el}
                    </p>
                  ))
                : ingredients.map((el, i) => (
                    <p
                      key={i}
                      className="text-theme-dark-grey2 text-sm font-medium leading-2"
                    >
                      {el}
                    </p>
                  ))}
            </div>
          </Link>
          <div className="mt-2 flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
            <p className="font-bold text-3xl leading-none">{`$${price}`}</p>
            <FoodForm
              onSubmit={(e: FormEvent) => handlerSubmit(e)}
              ref={amountInputRef}
            />
            {/*<form
              onSubmit={(e: FormEvent) => handlerSubmit(e)}
              className="flex items-center gap-x-2"
            >
              <input
                type="number"
                className="border-none outline-none text-center text-xs w-14 h-6 px-4 bg-theme-dark-black rounded-full"
                ref={amountInputRef}
              />
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="border-none outline-none bg-theme-green rounded-xl text-2xl p-1 font-bold"
              >
                <FiPlus />
              </button>
            </form>*/}
          </div>
          {!amountIsValid && (
            <p className="mt-4 text-left text-xs font-medium text-theme-dark-orange">
              Please enter a amount (1-5).
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
        <Image
          src={image as string}
          width={115}
          height={115}
          alt="product"
          className="object-cover object-center drop-shadow"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Food;
```

***FoodForm.tsx Component***

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import { FiPlus } from "react-icons/fi";

const FoodForm: React.FC<{ onSubmit: any; ref: any }> = forwardRef(
  ({ onSubmit }, ref) => {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="flex items-center gap-x-2">
        <input
          type="number"
          className="border-none outline-none text-center text-xs w-14 h-6 px-4 bg-theme-dark-black rounded-full"
          ref={ref}
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="border-none outline-none bg-theme-green rounded-xl text-2xl p-1 font-bold"
        >
          <FiPlus />
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
);

export default FoodForm;
```

I've reviewed and tried similar errors and questions from different web sites, but I couldn't get any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I fixed the error by editing the FoodForm component as follows.

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import { FiPlus } from "react-icons/fi";

const FoodForm = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, { onSubmit: any }>(
  ({ onSubmit }, ref) => {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="flex items-center gap-x-2">
        <input
          type="number"
          className="border-none outline-none text-center text-xs w-14 h-6 px-4 bg-theme-dark-black rounded-full"
          ref={ref}
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="border-none outline-none bg-theme-green rounded-xl text-2xl p-1 font-bold"
        >
          <FiPlus />
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
);

export default FoodForm;
```

Thanks!